# PHP, SimpleXML, CDATA and HTML entities

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, html-entities, cdata

I have some XML which contains CDATA.

For example the title: `<title><![CDATA[School&rsquo;s Latest News]]></title>`

When I parse the full XML document with simplexml_load_string, I am able to access the CDATA values using (string). So for example, I get the title:

`$title = (string)$news_xml -> {'news'} -> {'title'}`

The problem I have is that the ’ is not presented as a ' but instead as â€™

If I use html_entity_decode, I get the exact same thing.

If I use the LIBXML_NOCDATA option when calling simplexml_load_string I am able to look at the CDATA using print_r and don't have to explicitly call (string), but my HTML entities are still coming out garbled.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: The ' is represented as its unicode value (0x8217): http://www.rsquo.net/

Comment: Just to quash a recurrent myth of SimpleXML, which you've mostly avoided anyway, there is absolutely no reason to set LIBXML_NOCDATA with SimpleXML. There are many aspects of a SimpleXML object that `print_r` cannot see, because it is not a "real" PHP object, but a wrapper around lower-level data - a limitation of `print_r`, not of SimpleXML. You could try one of these instead: https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&rsquo;` is a unicode character (value 0x8217), see also http://www.rsquo.net/

If you send it to a browser (as I reckon you mean by `presented as`), make sure the encoding of the page is set to UTF-8.

Comment: That was it. But then why does utf8_decode output the character as a ?

Comment: @mattm591 no idea, probably because it has no equivalent for `&rsquo;` in ISO-8859-1. Note that `&rsquo;` is not ' but ´. It is a different character, with a different meaning.